# Group and count Dictionary Items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Dictionary<string, CachedImage>` with which I'd like to group the items, count the number of items in the group and iterate through each group if the count is greater than 6500.

The `CachedImage` class contains `Path` And `ExpiresUtc` properties that I am interested in.

My Linq-fu is sadly lacking with complex queries so this is as far as I have got and I think I've already messed up. I'm assuming what I want is possible.

Any help would be appreciated, especially with a quick walkthrough.

```
Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"(jpeg|png|bmp|gif)");
var groups= PersistantDictionary.Instance.ToList()
            .GroupBy(x => searchTerm.Match(x.Value.Path))
            .Select(y => new
                           {
                            Path = y.Key,
                            Expires = y.Select(z => z.Value.ExpiresUtc),
                            Count = y.Sum(z => z.Key.Count())
                           })
            .AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: I would use a `.Where(c => c.Value.Count() > 6500)` after the group by to prefilter the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var groups = PersistantDictionary.Instance.ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => searchTerm.Match(x.Value.Path).Value)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 6500);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} images for extension {1}", group.Count(), group.Key);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CachedImage> pair in group)
    {
        //Do stuff with each CachedImage.
    }
}
```

So to break this down:

```
PersistantDictionary.Instance.ToList()
```

Produces a list of `KeyValuePair<string, CachedImage>`.

```
.GroupBy(x => searchTerm.Match(x.Value.Path).Value)
```

Groups the list by the Regex match against the `Path` of the `CachedImage`. Note that I have used the `Value` property - the `Match` method returns a `Match` object, so it would be best to group by the actual text of the match. The outcome of this step will be an `IEnumerable` of `<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, CachedImage>>>`.

```
.Where(g => g.Count() > 6500);
```

This ensures that only those groups with > 6500 items will be retrieved.

Comment: Cheers! This looks promising. If I wanted to also check for the expiry date would it be something like this? 

`.Where(g => g.Count() > MaxFilesCount
                    || g.Select(a => a.Value.ExpiresUtc < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-MaxFileCachedDuration)).Count() > 0);`

Comment: @JamesSouth Yes, that looks correct. In that case you will retrieve a group which has either greater than `MaxFilesCount` members, or a group where one or more of its members feature an `ExpiresUtc` value less than the specified `DateTime`. If that sounds right you should be good to go.